# CSS Filter Works In Chrome and Firefox But Not IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

The CSS **filter** property works in Firefox and Chrome. How can I get this same affect to work in Internet Explorer. For more information on what the **filter** property is go here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason CSS Filter doesn't work in IE is because it's not supported in IE.

This feature is currently in development stage for modern IE. https://status.modern.ie/filters

Generally for any modern CSS features it's good practice to check 
http://caniuse.com to see which browsers actually support the property.